# Can't publish with .net version 4.0 on vs 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, .net-framework-version

I have an issue when trying to publish my site through Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
I'm targeting .net version 4, as this is the version running on the server I'm going to use. However, when I try and publish my site, I get the following error:

Exception in executing publishing: The tools version "4.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "12.0", "2.0", "3.5"

It then points me to the address of an xml saying the following:

< project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
< /project>

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: The tool version means MSBuild version. So are you using VS 2012? MSBuild 12.0 is for VS 2013.

Comment: I am using 2012. However, I have 2013 installed on the system as well. (I can't use it - it's bugging out, and even a reinstall won't help.) Also, the project was made in vs 2013, before it started messing up.

Comment: Can only guess that your VS/.NET installation is now corrupt. If possible, build another machine and retry.

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I go about that? I've already chosen 'repair' on vs 2012 and 2013. Would I just go about reinstalling the .net framework?

Comment: "**Build another machine and retry**"

Comment: Um, I'm afraid I don't have the spare time and resources to do that.

Comment: While you wasted so much time fixing it, you should have already built another one and started working for a long while. Think about it carefully.